# How do I create different methods for different tasks in Java, and then call them?

Tags: java, methods, call

I have been having trouble understanding the concept of methods for Java, and I need to write a code for a Grade Calculator program that is less messy than what I've got.

Here's what I have (it's all in one method):

```
public class GradeCalculator2{
    public static void main(String[]args){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int students;
        String studentName;

        System.out.println("Welcome to GradeCalculator program.");
        System.out.println("Author: Hayden Wires");
        System.out.println("Date: 10/25/2016");
        System.out.print("Enter the number of students:");
        students = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter next student's information:");
        System.out.print("Name:");
        studentName = sc.next();

        for(int i = students; i > 1; i++){

            double quizScore1;
            double quizScore2;
            double quizScore3;
            double quizScore4;
            double quizScore5;

            System.out.print("Quiz 1:");
            quizScore1 = sc.nextDouble();
            quizScore1 /= 100;
            quizScore1 *= .02;

            System.out.print("Quiz 2:");
            quizScore2 = sc.nextDouble();
            quizScore2 /= 100;
            quizScore2 *= .02;

            System.out.print("Quiz 3:");
            quizScore3 = sc.nextDouble();
            quizScore3 /= 100;
            quizScore3 *= .02;

            System.out.print("Quiz 4:");
            quizScore4 = sc.nextDouble();
            quizScore4 /= 100;
            quizScore4 *= .02;

            System.out.print("Quiz 5:");
            quizScore5 = sc.nextDouble();
            quizScore5 /= 100;
            quizScore5 *= .02;

            double totalQuizScores = quizScore1 + quizScore2 + quizScore3 + quizScore4 + quizScore5;
            totalQuizScores /= 5;

            double a1_Score;
            double a2_Score;
            double a3_Score;
            double a4_Score;
            double a5_Score;
            double a6_Score;

            System.out.print("Assignment 1:");
            a1_Score = sc.nextDouble();
            a1_Score /= 100;
            a1_Score *= .025;

            System.out.print("Assignment 2:");
            a2_Score = sc.nextDouble();
            a2_Score /= 100;
            a2_Score *= .025;

            System.out.print("Assignment 3:");
            a3_Score = sc.nextDouble();
            a3_Score /= 100;
            a3_Score *= .05;

            System.out.print("Assignment 4:");
            a4_Score = sc.nextDouble();
            a4_Score /= 100;
            a4_Score *= .05;

            System.out.print("Assignment 5:");
            a5_Score = sc.nextDouble();
            a5_Score /= 100;
            a5_Score *= .05;

            System.out.print("Assignment 6:");
            a6_Score = sc.nextDouble();
            a6_Score /= 100;
            a6_Score *= .1;

            double a1_a2_Scores = a1_Score + a2_Score;
            double a3_a4_a5_Scores = a3_Score + a4_Score + a5_Score;

            double assignmentScoresTotal = a1_a2_Scores + a3_a4_a5_Scores + a6_Score;
            assignmentScoresTotal /= 3;


            double mt1Score;
            System.out.print("Midterm 1:");
            mt1Score = sc.nextDouble();
            mt1Score /= 100;
            mt1Score *= .1;

            double mt2Score;
            System.out.print("Midterm 2:");
            mt2Score = sc.nextDouble();
            mt2Score /= 100;
            mt2Score *= .2;

            double mtScoresTotal = mt1Score + mt2Score;
            mtScoresTotal /= 2;

            double finalScore;
            System.out.print("Final:");
            finalScore = sc.nextDouble();
            finalScore /= 100;
            finalScore *= .3;

            double totalGrade = assignmentScoresTotal + totalQuizScores + mtScoresTotal + finalScore;
            totalGrade *= 100;
            totalGrade *= 2;

            System.out.println(studentName + "'S SCORE:" + totalGrade);

            String letterGrade;

            if (totalGrade >= 93){
                letterGrade = "A";
            } else if ((totalGrade >= 90)&&(totalGrade < 92)){
                letterGrade = "A-";
            } else if ((totalGrade >= 87)&&(totalGrade < 90)){
                letterGrade = "B+";
            } else if ((totalGrade >= 83)&&(totalGrade < 87)){
                letterGrade = "B";
            } else if ((totalGrade >= 80)&&(totalGrade < 83)){
                letterGrade = "B-";
            } else if ((totalGrade >= 77)&&(totalGrade < 80)){
                letterGrade = "C+";
            } else if ((totalGrade >= 74)&&(totalGrade < 77)){
                letterGrade = "C";
            } else if ((totalGrade >= 70)&&(totalGrade < 74)){
                letterGrade = "C-";
            } else if ((totalGrade >= 68)&&(totalGrade < 70)){
                letterGrade = "D+";
            } else if ((totalGrade >= 60)&&(totalGrade < 68)){
                letterGrade = "D";
            } else {
                letterGrade = "F";
            }
            System.out.println(studentName + "'S LETTER GRADE:" + letterGrade);
        }
    }
}
```

I understand this is very messy and probably very hard to read, but that's what I need help with. I know there's a way to make this program less redundant using methods, I just can't grasp the concept in context with this program.

Comment: This is all very well explained in Oracle's online Java tutorials.  I recommend you [start here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html)

Comment: This question would be better served by the good folks over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2):

Java is well designed Object Oriented Programming Language. And Object Oriented Philosophy is highly related to Inheritance. Java is builded on inheritance property of OOP. Because of inheritance you can not have global methods.

The following example is not good object oriented practice, it is just to show the procedure:

```
public class myClass{
public static void main(String[] args){
    f1();

}

private void f1(arg1, arg2){
//your code here
} //end of method f1
} //end of class
```

It is not good Object Oriented practice because you generally separate your main (driver) class and other classes and in main class you have just main method.

Answer (score 1):

To shorten your code, you need to look for patterns!

See how you process the score of each quiz and each assignment in a similar fashion?

You always process quizzes like this:

```
System.out.print("Quiz <insert a number here>:");
quizScoreX = sc.nextDouble();
quizScoreX /= 100;
quizScoreX *= .02;
```

The only thing that differs here is the number after the word "Quiz".

You always process assignments like this:

```
System.out.print("Assignment <insert number here>:");
aX_Score = sc.nextDouble();
aX_Score /= 100;
aX_Score *= <insert number here>;
```

The only things that differ here are the number after the word "Assignment" and the number you multiply the score by.

See the patterns?

That means we can group the process of getting the score of each quiz and each assignment into two methods:

```
private static double getQuizScore(int number) {
    System.out.print("Quiz " + Integer.toString(number) + ":");
    double quizScore = sc.nextDouble();
    quizScore /= 100;
    quizScore *= .02;
    return quizScore;
}

private static double getAssignmentScore(int number, double multiplier) {
    System.out.print("Assignment " + Integer.toString(number) + ":");
    doubke assignmentScore = sc.nextDouble();
    assignmentScore /= 100;
    assignmentScore *= multiplier;
    return assignmentScore;

}
```

Also note that you are getting the scores of 5 quizzes. Every time, what you are doing is simply incrementing the quiz number. And you add them together at the end. This can be simplified to:

```
private static double getTotalQuizScore() {
    double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
        total += getQuizScore(i + 1);
    }

    return total;
}
```

You can then use these two methods in your code like this:

```
        double totalQuizScores = getTotalQuizScore();
        totalQuizScores /= 5;

        double a1_Score = getAssignmentScore(1, 0.25);
        double a2_Score = getAssignmentScore(2, 0.25);
        double a3_Score = getAssignmentScore(3, 0.05);
        double a4_Score = getAssignmentScore(4, 0.05);
        double a5_Score = getAssignmentScore(5, 0.05);
        double a6_Score = getAssignmentScore(6, 0.1);

        double a1_a2_Scores = a1_Score + a2_Score;
        double a3_a4_a5_Scores = a3_Score + a4_Score + a5_Score;

        double assignmentScoresTotal = a1_a2_Scores + a3_a4_a5_Scores + a6_Score;
        assignmentScoresTotal /= 3;


        double mt1Score;
        System.out.print("Midterm 1:");
        mt1Score = sc.nextDouble();
        mt1Score /= 100;
        mt1Score *= .1;

        double mt2Score;
        System.out.print("Midterm 2:");
        mt2Score = sc.nextDouble();
        mt2Score /= 100;
        mt2Score *= .2;

        double mtScoresTotal = mt1Score + mt2Score;
        mtScoresTotal /= 2;

        double finalScore;
        System.out.print("Final:");
        finalScore = sc.nextDouble();
        finalScore /= 100;
        finalScore *= .3;

        double totalGrade = assignmentScoresTotal + totalQuizScores + mtScoresTotal + finalScore;
        totalGrade *= 100;
        totalGrade *= 2;

        System.out.println(studentName + "'S SCORE:" + totalGrade);

        String letterGrade;

        if (totalGrade >= 93){
            letterGrade = "A";
        } else if ((totalGrade >= 90)&&(totalGrade < 92)){
            letterGrade = "A-";
        } else if ((totalGrade >= 87)&&(totalGrade < 90)){
            letterGrade = "B+";
        } else if ((totalGrade >= 83)&&(totalGrade < 87)){
            letterGrade = "B";
        } else if ((totalGrade >= 80)&&(totalGrade < 83)){
            letterGrade = "B-";
        } else if ((totalGrade >= 77)&&(totalGrade < 80)){
            letterGrade = "C+";
        } else if ((totalGrade >= 74)&&(totalGrade < 77)){
            letterGrade = "C";
        } else if ((totalGrade >= 70)&&(totalGrade < 74)){
            letterGrade = "C-";
        } else if ((totalGrade >= 68)&&(totalGrade < 70)){
            letterGrade = "D+";
        } else if ((totalGrade >= 60)&&(totalGrade < 68)){
            letterGrade = "D";
        } else {
            letterGrade = "F";
        }
        System.out.println(studentName + "'S LETTER GRADE:" + letterGrade);
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention, you also need to move `sc` to class level so that the methods can access it:

Move this line:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

outside of the main method and add `private static` at the beginning:

```
private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are running the same calculations repeatedly:

```
System.out.print("Quiz 1:");
quizScore1 = sc.nextDouble();
quizScore1 /= 100;
quizScore1 *= .02;
```

This could be replaced with a method

```
double readScore(Scanner sc, String title, double weight)
{
    System.out.print(title);
    double result = sc.nextDouble();
    result /= 100.0;
    result *= weight;
    return result;
}
```

Then, you main function would look like:

```
quizScore1 = readScore(sc, "Quiz 1", 0.02);
:
a2_Score = readScore(sc, "Assignment 2", 0.025);
etc...
```

So that would remove a lot of repeated code from your main function.

After that, you should probably learn about arrays, so you don't have a1_score through a6_score, etc...